How to use a ligature that is in the dlig without using all of them
In older versions, Junicode used to have the ft and fft ligatures when setting Ligatures=TeX. Recent version, though, seem to consider them as Rare.
For consistency with other books in a series (and as it can help understanding a text in German, especially in sections with historic spellings), I’d really like to use these ligatures by default (it is easier to insert e.g. \kern0pt in those cases where the ligature is wrong rather than to insert a command in every instance of ft and fft). Setting Ligatures=Rare, though, will also enable st and ct ligatures, among others, which are not desirable in modern German texts.
I’ve read a bit through the github issues and discussions in the Junicode repo but I have to admit I do not know much about the font-related intricacies of TeX at all and thus I really do not want to screw around in places I do not understand the workings of.
Also, older questions on tex.sx hint at feature files but from what I’ve read, these have been deprecated quite some time ago and cannot be considered a working solution.
Therefore, I’d really appreciate any ideas how I can have ft and fft ligatures without the others defined in the “rare” set.
I currently use XeTeX and hence, I’d prefer solutions for it.
While I’m generally open for lua-based solutions as well, I have not yet tried going along this path as I’ve not used Lua at all up until now and would like to avoid experimenting right now while in the middle of typesetting a book in a series. But I’ll consider the change if need be.  —
I’ve read (e.g. in How to suppress a "Rare" ligature that pre-empts a "Common" ligature for the same character pair?) about solutions in luatex that I think might be adaptable to my needs, and about the selnolig package (e.g. in How to keep a "rare" ligature from interfering with a "common" ligature?) which requires lua and seems to be unmaintained (last release was in late 2015 – would that still work anyway?) [edit: not true, see comment by @Mico below].
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{junicode}

\begin{document}
No ft or fft ligatures by default: Schrift – schrifftthum – Lust


\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Rare}
Here, ft and fft are a ligature, but also st: Schrift – schrifftthum – Lust

\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=RareOff}
note, that »schrifftthum« is a non-standard, historical spelling variant,
but one where the fft ligature can really help sorting through the consonants.

fontspec is being loaded by the junicode package.

\end{document}


The selnolig package is not unmaintained.

Thanks for pointing that out; I have edited that part of my question.

Since you've mentioned that you're willing to consider switching from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX, I can't resist pointing out that the selnolig package, while designed mainly to suppress certain ligatures selectively, can also be used to suppress certain ligatures globally.
For instance, to suppress the ct and st ligatures globally, while leaving all other ligatures -- including ft and fft -- unaffected, it suffices to issue the instructions
\nolig{ct}{c|t}
\nolig{st}{s|t}

after selnolig is loaded. In general, user-specified \nolig instructions should be placed in the preamble.

A final remark: If your document employs both babel and selnolig, then selnolig should be loaded after babel.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{junicode}
\usepackage{selnolig} % note: no language option specified

\begin{document}

\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Rare}

ft fft st ct     % no ligatures suppressed

\nolig{st}{s|t}
\nolig{ct}{c|t}
ft fft st ct     % suppress 'st' and 'ct' ligatures, but not 'ft' and 'fft' ligatures

\end{document}


Thank you for this quick and comprehensive answer!
I will try to make the switch to LuaLaTeX – just have to check that everything else still works and find the time to fix those things that don’t.
That (and because I have not tested it, though I do believe you) is why I won’t accept the answer just yet, as perhaps a XeLaTeX answer might still come around.

I have decided to go along this route. While it entailed a bit of work to adapt everything to lualatex, the results seem to be worth it. Thanks to @mico and @david-carlisle!

I'd use lualatex, but if using xelatex you can use a pair of character classes to insert a kern to suppress ligatures.

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{junicode}

\newXeTeXintercharclass\classt
\newXeTeXintercharclass\classbeforet
\XeTeXinterchartoks \classbeforet \classt {\kern0pt }
\XeTeXcharclass `\t \classt
\XeTeXcharclass `\c \classbeforet
\XeTeXcharclass `\s \classbeforet
\begin{document}

\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Rare}

ft fft st ct     % no ligatures suppressed

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1

ft fft st ct     % suppress 'st' and 'ct' ligatures, but not 'ft' and 'fft' ligatures

\end{document}

this might (will) also affect hyphenation though.

Thanks for that! I’d done quite some work to get rid of the XeTeXinterchartoks (as you say, due to the impact on hyphenation) and stashed the rest away in an obscure include so that I completely forgot about that.
The impact on hyphenation and your suggestion to use lualatex (which means it’s two–nil for lua right now) do bring me closer to adapting it.
